# Get max number depending of relations

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this query:

```
 SELECT
                   MAX([D].[DesignKey]) AS [DesignKey]
                   FROM [Project] AS [P]
                       INNER JOIN [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [DG].[ProjectKey]
                       INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DG].[DesignGroupId] = [D].[DesignGroupId]
                   GROUP BY
                          [P].[ProjectKey]
                        , [D].[Name]
                        ORDER BY DesignKey
```

My relation is: One project can have multiple `DesignGroups` and one `Design` can have multiple `DesignGroups` but one design CAN NOT have multiple Projects

That I want to do is to select max design key number of each `DesignGroup` how can I achieve that? With my query it returns all DesignKeys, it does not care if it last of each designGroup. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT [DG].[DesignGroupId], MAX([D].[DesignKey]) AS [DesignKey]
FROM [DesignGroup] [DG] JOIN
     [Design] [D]
     ON [DG].[DesignGroupId] = [D].[DesignGroupId]
GROUP BY [DG].[DesignGroupId];
```

Note that the `PROJECT` table is not needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

use DesignGroupId on group by and selection

```
SELECT
                  DesignGroupId, MAX([D].[DesignKey]) AS [DesignKey]
                   FROM [Project] AS [P]
                       INNER JOIN [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [DG].[ProjectKey]
                       INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DG].[DesignGroupId] = [D].[DesignGroupId]
                   GROUP BY
                          DesignGroupId
                       ORDER BY DesignKey
```